# PayPal Recurring Donations Code Issue

Tags: paypal, donations

I am trying to set up a recurring donations option on a non-profit site. I'm not very good with forms, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. The only value when you hit submit on the website is to make a $5 recurring donation. Is there a way to allow a different value? I found this code on the internet so I might not be setting it up correctly. Thank you!

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<br />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select name="os0">
        <option value="Donate">Donate : $5.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
        <option value="Donate">Donate : $10.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
        <option value="Donate">Donate : $20.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
        <option value="Donate">Donate : $30.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
        <option value="Donate">Donate : $40.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
        <option value="Donate">Donate : $50.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<p>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----">
  <input type="image" src="http://fallforthebook.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/donation-button.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" style="border:0px;">
  <img class="colorbox-9288"  alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"><br />
```

Answer (score 2):

The code posted is an encrypted button code. No changes can be made to the code. Kindly refer to the sample code below

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@test.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donate To My Organization">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1234">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">

<table>
<tr><td>When would you like this donation to Recur</td></tr>
<tr><td><select name="t3">
 <option value="D">Daily </option>
 <option value="M">Monthly </option>
 <option value="Y">Yearly </option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td>How many times would you like this to recur? (including this payment)</td></tr>
<tr><td><select name="srt">
<option value="0">Never End</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select></td></tr>

<tr><td>Enter your Donation Amount</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="a3" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but21.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you all for so much! I changed my code to this and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try to differentiate the option values with a unique name. Example Donate1, Donate 2 and so on.

```
<select name="os0">
    <option value="Donate1">Donate : $5.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
    <option value="Donate2">Donate : $10.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
    <option value="Donate3">Donate : $20.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
    <option value="Donate4">Donate : $30.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
    <option value="Donate5">Donate : $40.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
    <option value="Donate6">Donate : $50.00 USD &#8211; monthly</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that button is unable to detect the options that you have listed is because the button is an encrypted button which will not take effect with any other code you present in the form as it's already fixed and using the encrypted information.

The best solution is to follow the steps in the link below and you will be able to create a new button under your PayPal account. Currently, the button code that you have provided is under different PayPal account because you copied from somewhere else which belong to that person.

https://www.angelleye.com/how-to-create-a-paypal-button/

Moreover, as for your inquiry on making the donation as recurring, this feature is no longer available when using the PayPal Donation button. The only option is to make a recurring donation is by creating a "Subscription" button.

You can use the sample button from @PP_MTS_Azleen answer for the subscription button. But make sure to change the value for this code to your PayPal account email address: